# Laravel Webpack "mix.scripts" working but scripts not loading in browser

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

Here is my webpack code:

```
...
mix.js('source/_assets/js/main.js', 'js')
    .sass('source/_assets/sass/main.scss', 'css')
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
    }).version();

mix.scripts([
    'source/_assets/js/theme/jquery.js',
    'source/_assets/js/theme/plugins.js',
    'source/_assets/js/theme/functions.js'
], 'source/assets/build/js/all.js');
```

In my head I have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/main.css', 'assets/build') }}">` to load my styles and `<script src="{{ mix('js/all.js', 'assets/build') }}"></script>` in my footer to load my scripts.  I run `npm run watch` and receive no errors, but my page is blank. In my source code, I can see both compiled files correctly inserted into my page and when clicked can view the compiled code.

Although using webpack is new for me, it seems I have done everything correctly but I can't seem to figure out why scripts are not loading.  On another note, If I hard code my scripts separately, i.e `<script src="https://www.studiorooster.com/packages/canvas_5/HTML/js/jquery.js"></script>...`, the page loads correctly. Thank you.